# Exception during IXmlSerializable.WriteXml when attempting to write an inner tag

Tags: c#, xml, ixmlserializable

Here is a test class:

```
    [XmlRoot("Test")]
    class Test : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public string Attr { get; set; }
        // ... more properties here...

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString("attr", Attr);
            writer.WriteStartElement("InnerTest"); // <-- exception
            // ... write inner stuff 
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

When I call WriteXml, an exception is thrown:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteEndStartTag(Boolean empty)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.AutoComplete(Token token)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement(String localName)
   at Tests.Test.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
```

In examples on the internet this code doesn't cause any issues (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly), yet for me it doesn't work. What can be the reason?

**Update:** 
Eventually, I would like the class to be serialized like this:

```
<Test attr="..."><InnerTest>...</InnerTest></Test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be more about how you're calling the serializer than how the WriteXml code is implemented. For example in LINQPad I did this:

```
Test t = new Test() { Attr = "cat" };       

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));      
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(w, t);  
w.ToString().Dump();
```

And I received this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Test attr="cat">
  <InnerTest />
</Test>
```

Comment: Indeed, I was calling WriteXml directly and apparently, that was a wrong way to test the serialization. Thanks!